# Laravel: Excluding routes from VerifyCsrfToken middleware programmatically

Tags: laravel, csrf-protection

I would like to know if there's a way I can programmatically add route to **$except** variable in **VerifyCsrfToken** class.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
    {
        /**
         * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $except = [
            //
        ];
    }
```

I am developing a package that listens to webhooks/postback from a payment gateway. It would be nicer if my custom route would be added to **$except** variable upon installation of the package.

Thanks

Comment: It would be hard make changes because it takes fresh request in each page refresh, if you are not reloading page then you could do it. Otherwise writing to the file would work.

Comment: I wouldn't call "programmatically" if you are talking about doing something only upon installation of the package. But, what about extend it into a custom class, and make it read the exception from the configuration files?

Comment: @Amarnasan if custom class will be created, I think I need to add it in the Kernel

Comment: You could just programmatically include your custom routes into that variable on your package installation. Simply read then write on the VerifyCsrfToken.php file.

Comment: @doncadavona thanks. Do you mind showing codes how to implement it? :D

Comment: Something like this: $file = 'app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php';
 file_put_contents($file, str_replace('$except','$except=["custom/route/to/exclude",', file_get_contents($file)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to add my custom route to api.php

```
file_put_contents(
 base_path('routes/api.php'),
 file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/stubs/make/routes.stub'),
 FILE_APPEND
);
```

VerifyCsrfToken middleware does not intercept routes in **api.php**